# timeanddate clock

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how is the time in [Time and Date Website](http://www.timeanddate.com/) under the Current Time tab is done?

I copied the CSS and the JavaScript and put together this but the time isn't going as the time and date website: [My Website](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/test/test.htm)

JavaScript:

```
et=1364486376;function f0(d){return ld[d.getUTCDay()]+','+' '+lm[d.getUTCMonth()]+' '+d.getUTCDate()+','+' '+d.getUTCFullYear()+' at '+((d.getUTCHours()+11)%12+1)+':'+p2(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'+p2(d.getUTCSeconds())+' '+_ap(d);}
function f1(d){return ld[d.getUTCDay()]+','+' '+lm[d.getUTCMonth()]+' '+d.getUTCDate()+','+' '+d.getUTCFullYear()+' at '+p2(d.getUTCHours())+':'+p2(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'+p2(d.getUTCSeconds());}
function f2(d){return ((d.getUTCHours()+11)%12+1)+':'+p2(d.getUTCMinutes());}
function f3(d){return ''+p2(d.getUTCSeconds());}
function f4(d){return ''+_ap(d);}
function f5(d){return ld[d.getUTCDay()];}
function f6(d){return sm[d.getUTCMonth()]+' '+d.getUTCDate()+','+' '+d.getUTCFullYear();}
function f7(d){return ''+sm[d.getUTCMonth()];}
function f8(d){return ''+d.getUTCFullYear();}
function f9(d){return ''+d.getUTCDate();}
function f10(d){return sd1[d.getUTCDay()];}
cks={clk_hm:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f2},ij0:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f3},clk_am:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f4},ij1:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f5},ij2:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f6},cal_m:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f7},cal_y:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f8},cal_d:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f9},cal_w:{t:[{o:-14400,a:'EDT',d:1}],f:f10}};
lm=[];lm[2]='March';sm=[];sm[2]='Mar';ld=[];ld[2]='Tuesday';ld[3]='Wednesday';ld[4]='Thursday';ld[5]='Friday';sd1=[];sd1[2]='Tue';sd1[3]='Wed';sd1[4]='Thu';sd1[5]='Fri';
function _ap(d){var t=Math.floor(d.getTime()/1E3)%86400;if(t===0){return 'Midnight';}if(t==43200){return 'Noon';}if(t<43200){return 'AM';}return 'PM';}
```

Can someone tell me what i have to fix or add to make it work?

Comment: You need to call `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` to perform periodic updates. You're not doing either.

Comment: I do not see any of those functions on the site, so i can't imagine how they are doing it.

Comment: When I look at the script in the web inspector, I see the `setTimeout` call, but it's not in the original HTML. This implies that it's loading Javascript dynamically. I'm not inclined to try to trace through all the minimized JS looking for how it does this.

Comment: There are many clock widgets you can download, google for them.

Comment: @Barmar I was able to get some idea from CodeBlend and do exactly that... :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the scripts that the website has? I believe there would need to be some dynamic code such as JavaScript underneath.

A quick Google lead me here but there could be better resources;
[Current Running Time with Javascript](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?44981-Current-Running-Time-with-Javascript)

However you do it, you will need to update the UI every second somehow.

Comment: I looked at the source but there is no code which shows how the time is being updated. I added what appears to be the script.

Comment: Maybe use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ticktoo/mKvzZ/ Do you really have to have that same clock from timeanddate.com?

Comment: I was able to manipulate the script to fit my need :) Thanks for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Even if I Copy entire website, Clicking `save as` in a folder on my desktop, the time-script won't work.This clearly indicates, apart from `JavaScript,CSS and HTML`, there is some server side script(probably PHP), that is called periodically and hence time is updated accordingly.

Even the code that you copied from the website contains line

```
/scripts/tzq.php?type=homecity',1,'Set Home Location'
```

Where is `tzq.php` file?
Thus, simply copying the javascript function won't work.I would suggest, either you store the time that you are displaying in your website in a javascript variables.

```
Eg:
var hh=12;
var mm=16
var ss=16
```

And call a java-script function every seconds and update the above three variables.
Or write a javascript code that displays the current server time from scratch.

**timeanddate.com also provides API for developers.Why don't you try their** [API](http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/)?

Comment: I updated the page and it works now, how I want it. Thanks for looking into it anyway.